# AWS S3 upload or EC2 upload to handle permissions

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I'm trying to find out what is the best storage service for my specific problem.

**The Application**

I'm developing a mobile app with Xamarin (.NET). Each user has to register and log in to use my service. Each user can be in several Groups where he hast the permission to store files in (each file about 200kb). My Backend is a EC2 instance hosting Cassandra as my database.

**The Problems**

I think about using AWS S3 for storing the files.

Question #1: 
Should i directly upload to S3 or should i upload to EC2, handle the permissions and then store it in S3. When using direct upload to S3, i have the advantage of much less bandwith used on my EC2 instance. For direct uploading i have to provide a Token Vending Machine, which has two modes for providing the credentials i need to interact with S3: anonymous and identity. As i read the anonymous approach is mostly user for read-only scenarios. But for the identity approach the user has to register in a browser windows, which is absolutely nothing that i want for my users.

> The application initiates communication with the TVM by bringing up a
>   browser on the mobile device to enable the user to register a user
>   name and password with the TVM. The TVM derives a secret key from the
>   password. The TVM stores the user name and secret key for future
>   reference.

Is it even possible to handle the permissions i need(each user can only upload and download files to groups which he belongs to)only with assigning AWS permissions to the TVM credentials?

Question #2:
Should i maybe consider storing each file directly in cassandra, since every file is only about 200kb? Problem here is, that the same files could be accessed several times per second.

Answer (score 0):

I would use S3. That way you don't have to worry about bandwidth and permissions on the file.  You do have interact with the Amazon S3 and IAM Service (Their authorization service). You can do this through the API and your language of choice (Python, Ruby, Java, etc)

If you are concerned about being tied to Amazon you can potentially setup something like OpenStack Storage (compatible with the S3 API) in your own datacenter and move your data to it.  The files would still be handled by your initial application since your code would be "S3 compatible"